# Best way to run Macro on LibreOffice or OpenOffice SubForm "Fill parameters" Event

Tags: python, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base, openoffice-base

I try for more than a week to fill out a SQL query parameter by running a macro on the "**Fill Parameters**" event in the subform by searching for a method to fill the parameter under the **Parameters** object with **MRI** without success.

Searches for guides and code samples on Google and the relevant forums also found nothing.

Have I missed something or am I looking in the wrong place? Thanks in advance!

Sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Table1" WHERE "Record-Id" = :Record-Id
```

Macro code to display an event object in **Python**:

```
def main (oEvent):
   ctx = XSCRIPTONTONT.getComponentContext ();
   mri (ctx, oEvent);
```

Comment: You [also posted here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/154154/best-way-to-run-macro-on-libreoffice-or-openoffice-subform-fill-parameters-event/), and @Ratslinger's answer is a good one.

Comment: @JimK I already have a much better solution than the improvised solutions I got there, I will publish it here soon.